# C# / C++ Callback Class (not function) Interop - howto?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, com, interop

*Apologies if there is a duplicate - I have struggled to find an answer (I have found a few questions around C++ functions that use Function callbacks, and some answers that use Classes as callbacks when called from C/C++ but..*

- I am in C#.
- I am calling a C++ function
- I can not change the signature of the C++ function.
- Also, I am using the dynamic method of p/invoke rather then the static binding (my example below);

I can handle the situation where a function takes a simple value, or a struct containing simple values, and returns simple values, but in this instance I have a C function which is taking a call-back object.

Following some ideas online, I tried to make a class that had the same signature, then pinned that class, and passed it in., but I get the C# error of 'Object is non-Blittable' (which it doesn't have any variables in it!).

Header file:

*again apologies if there are any mistakes in my example, I've tried to strip all non relevant code and explode the macros, but I hope you understand the essence of what is going on*

```c
    struct someData_t
    {
    int length; /**< JSON data length */
    char* pData; /*< JSON data */
    };

    namespace FOO {
    class ICallback
    {
    public: virtual ~ICallback() {}

        virtual void Callback(const someData_t &response) = 0;
    };
    }

    extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void process(const someData_t *inData, FOO::ICallback *listener);
```

My C# file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Scratchpad {
    class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("I'm in Managed C#...");

        IntPtr user32 = NativeMethods.LoadLibrary(@"somelongpath\my_c.dll");

        IntPtr pAddressOfFunctionToCall = NativeMethods.GetProcAddress(user32, "process");

        process proc = (process)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(pAddressOfFunctionToCall, typeof(process));

        String someJson = "{ \"type\":\"someTestJson\"}";
        byte[] rawdata = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(someJson);

        someData myData = new someData();
        int dataLength = rawdata.Length * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(byte)); // I realise byte is size 1 but..

        myData.length = rawdata.Length;

        myData.pData = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(dataLength);
        Marshal.Copy(rawdata, 0, myData.pData, dataLength);

        Console.Out.WriteLine("Size of mydata: " + Marshal.SizeOf(myData));
        IntPtr unmanagedADdr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(myData));

        Marshal.StructureToPtr(myData, unmanagedADdr, true);

        // ################################################################
        // FIXME: This area still working
        Callbacker myCallback = new Callbacker();

        GCHandle gch = GCHandle.Alloc(myCallback, GCHandleType.Pinned);

        IntPtr mycallbackPtr = gch.AddrOfPinnedObject();

        // FIXME: close of working area.
        // ################################################################
        // CALL THE FUNCTION!
        proc(unmanagedADdr, mycallbackPtr);


        myData = (someData) Marshal.PtrToStructure(unmanagedADdr, typeof(someData));

        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(unmanagedADdr);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(myData.pData);
        gch.Free();
        unmanagedADdr = IntPtr.Zero;

        bool result = NativeMethods.FreeLibrary(user32);

        Console.Out.WriteLine("Fini!)");
    }

    private delegate void process(IntPtr data, IntPtr callback);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct someData { 
        public int length; 
        public IntPtr pData; 
    }

    private class Callbacker {
        public void Callback(someData response) {
        Console.WriteLine("callback Worked!!!");
        }
    }

    }

    static class NativeMethods {
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procedureName);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions welcome

Comment: You cannot pass pointer to managed class here, because Your managed class Callbacker does not implement FOO::ICallback interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create some un-managed wrapper for Your managed `Callbacker` class which implements `ICallback` interface.
Something like this:

```
typedef void (*PointerToManagedFunctionToInvoke)(const someData_t&);

class UnmanagedDelegate : public FOO::ICallback {
    private:
        PointerToManagedFunctionToInvoke managedCallback;
    public:
        UnmanagedDelegate(PointerToManagedFunctionToInvoke inManagedCallback)
        : managedCallback(inManagedCallback) {}

        virtual void Callback(const someData_t &response)
        {
            managedCallback(response);
        }
};

// Export this to managed part
UnmanagedDelegate* CreateUnmanagedDelegate(PointerToManagedFunctionToInvoke inManagedCallback)
{
    return new UnmanagedDelegate(inManagedCallback);
}
```

Then at C# part You could create a delegate to marshal as `PointerToManagedFunctionToInvoke`, pass it to `CreateUnmanagedDelegate` receive unmanaged implementation of `ICallback` and use that to pass to your `process`

Please be aware that `managedCallback` should stay allocated at C# side while `UnmanagedDelegate` class object is alive. And You should delete the `UnmanagedDelegate` object when it is not used anymore.

OR You could use thin C++/CLI to implement this wrapper.

Comment: Thank you very much! It took me a while to work through and get it implemented - what I did was made a 3rd library which I bound straight to the C# project without going through pInvoke. 

When I compiled your code though it objected to the lack of a semicolon on the end of the class (I'm not the worlds best C++ programmer, but is that right !?)

I suspect now that I have this wrapper layer in C I could redefine how my structs are to include from a common .h file... but it works. Thank you so much!

Comment: Yeah, there should be semicolon after class declaration - my bad - did not compile the code to check for syntax errors. You are welcome, BUT - please be VERY CAREFUL with memory management - one simple mistake could lead to memory leaks and errors. This is not usual C# garbage-collected code.